# How to make a reusable UITableView in a separate xib file

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls

So i'm still a newbie, and trying to get my bearings.

I know for sure I need to reuse this UITableView, but I want to share it so that some of my screens in my storyboard, will reference this same custom control.

For some reason when I add a Empty XIB view file, and drag the UITableView, I can't seem to get the same interface of configuring prototype cells, why is this the case?

What am I doing wrong, is my approach off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using **XIB** you cannot add prototype cell inside `tableView`.

Comment: You **can't** add prototype cell in **XIB**, you can **only** add prototype cell in **StoryBoard**.

Comment: You need to add another xib for the cell if you use XIB with tableview.